# How to use Sinch VOIP with iOS 13 or higher?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, ios13, sinch

I have an app in Android and iOS that uses Sinch videocalls but since the iOS 13 launching the video the iOS 13 sends is bad, it looks like static. I've discovered that if during the videocall I use the iPhone in landscape orientation  the video transmitted is normal. This problem happens even with the sinch demo. Any ideas to solve this?

I've tried: use multiple connections, updating the framework to the last version, in multiple devices, modifiy the frame from the callAsyncLocalVideoFrameHandler.

I expect to be able to send good video from devices with iOS 13 of higher and iPadOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we are aware of the issue, it's caused by a compatibility issue between iOS 13's H264 Codec and the WebRTC version we use on our SDK.

We are working to fix that. There will be a new major iOS SDK release to support iOS 13, at the moment we do not recommend customers to release new versions of their apps with iOS 13/Xcode 11 support.

Your current apps will still work on devices running iOS <12 and the new iOS 13, as long as they are not built with XCode 11.

iOS 13 brings also new directives to use VoIP Push on Apple devices, this will also cause changes on how customers integrate any VoIP SDK, if you use VoIP Push notifications.

See note and links on our website.
https://www.sinch.com/docs/resources/downloads/index_vvv.html#info-ios-13-voip-push-changes

Jorge Siqueira - Sinch Voice & Video.

Comment: It would be great if there is an estimated timeline when the issue will be resolved. Thank you! :)

Comment: 2 weeks is a good estimation, we are finishing the implementation and will soon start the RC tests.

Comment: Jorge, is there any news about the release of the new version?

Comment: New RC is under testing and should be release next week. you can open a ticket at support@sinch.com to request access to the RC before the official release, if you want.

Comment: Official IOS SDK with iOS 13 support is available on our download page. https://developers.sinch.com/page/downloads

Comment: @JorgeSiqueira still facing issues in background mode need help

Answer (score 1):

I also see problems with iOS 13 and Sinch Video call. I have tried to go back and build with Xcode 10.3 but that does not help either. iOS 12 still works like you say